# How can i use a Session in case of a file download situation in c#, not asp?

Tags: c#, web

I'm trying to download set of files from web and im writing a C# console app. And im using web client to do this. The problem is it wont able to download the file unless i open the file download link in the browser. I don't know the reason why this happens. I was thinking this has something to do with sessions. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code

```
private bool DownloadFile(string pdfId, string filetype)
{
        try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                 webClient.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/" + pdfId + ".pdf", "E:\\Backups\\File" + filetype + "_" + pdfId + ".pdf");

            }                           
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Execption = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }         
}
```

The error im getting is

> "The remote server returned an error:(404) not found"

Comment: That's strange. I've tried your code and it downloads the file without throwing any error...

Comment: are you on a corporate network when you run this? Just wondering if there's a proxy or something that's blocking your request.

Comment: @Pikoh> Im sorry check the question again, try sending k36062, k15547, j63390 values in a loop as pdfId. Not one by one.

Comment: @Jay > no im not on a corporate network

Comment: I've tried also sending the 3 pdf names in a loop. Works flawless for me. It downloads them without error. So maybe something in your network?

Comment: maybe it is, if i open these download file links in my browser and after I run this app, it works properly.

Comment: @Pikoh > is it possible for me to use a session to do this? maybe through that i can overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work, are you passing the pdf ids correctly?

[image: Example of working code]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] List = { "k36062", "k15547", "j63390" };
        foreach(string line in List)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DownloadFile(line, "pdf"));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string DownloadFile(string pdfId, string filetype)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/" + pdfId + ".pdf", "C:\\Temp\\files\\" + filetype + "_" + pdfId + ".pdf");

            }
            return "Downloaded No errors";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But when i run the code it returns the same error. thanks for trying.

Comment: But It download the files when i open these download links in the browser before I run the code.

Comment: It must be something to do with your local network then? This code worked for me and I have never browsed to that website before. I never attempted to individually test it or anything. Just ran the code and it worked.